# Right way to initialize preference XML for PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-preferences

In the Android documentation available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html), their example sets the XML for `PreferenceFragmentCompat` this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

But in this new support class, we must override the method `onCreatePreferences`, where the same XML file can also be inflated:

```
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

What is the point of this new method that we have to override since the old way is still working?